# How to change the dev position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

In my browsers Firefox and Chrome I don't get any errors or warnings.  It's just practice. I'm taking a course in javascript and Dynamic HTML. If anybody cares to look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it. There's got to be something that I'm not getting right.

I want to create new divs as the page loads. These divs will appear as an ordered group that changes depending upon external data from a JSON file. I will need to do this with a for a loop because there are over 100 divs needed.

[image: demo]

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div id="showFilters">
        <!-- GROUP -->
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 text-center mt-4">
        <p>Add new group</p>
        <a id="addFilter" class="bg-primary text-white pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $('#addFilter').click(function () {
        count++;
        let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
            '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="name">Name</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="latin">Latin</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="latin" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][latin]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="field">Select a field</label>'+
            '<select id="field" class="form-select" name="filters['+count+'][field]">'+
            '<option value="1">CheckBox</option>'+
            '<option value="2">Color</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="showGroups"> '+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="w-100 text-center">'+
            '<p>Add new subgroup.</p>'+
            '<a onclick="addChildFilter()" class="bg-danger text-info pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">'+
            '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>'+
            '</a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        $('#showFilters').append(html);
    });
    function addChildFilter() {
        count++;
        let selectedField = $('#field').val();
        if (selectedField == 1) {
            let html = '<div class="w-100">'+
                '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 position-relative">'+
                '<label for="name">Check Box Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            $('#showGroups').append(html);
        }
        if (selectedField == 2) {
            let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="name">Color Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="code">Code Color</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="code" class="form-control jscolor" name="filters['+count+'][code]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            $('#showGroups').append(html);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed all of your issues in the  above demo. Click `Run code snippet` to see.

The issue is **you don't use dynamic element id to render**.

For example, in `function addChildFilter()`, you still use the id of the first groups `$('#field').val()`. You should dynamic it too.

So I add an id for each groups: `id="group' + count + '"`. And then, I can easy to query the field value in any groups by `let selectedField = $('#group' + groupId).find('.field').first().val();`

And we also have to spend the new  HTML into right group by `$('#group' + groupId).find('.showGroups').append(html);`.

In all cases we dynamic add/remove HTML. You should use class, or use element Id with a specific number for eachs.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div id="showFilters">
        <!-- GROUP -->
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 text-center mt-4">
        <p>Add new group</p>
        <a id="addFilter" class="bg-primary text-white pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $('#addFilter').click(function () {
        count++;
        let html = '<div id="group' + count + '" class="position-relative">'+
            '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="name">Name</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="latin">Latin</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="latin" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][latin]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="field">Select a field</label>'+
            '<select class="form-select field" name="filters['+count+'][field]">'+
            '<option value="1">CheckBox</option>'+
            '<option value="2">Color</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="showGroups" class="showGroups"> '+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="w-100 text-center">'+
            '<p>Add new subgroup.</p>'+
            '<a onclick="addChildFilter('+count+')" class="bg-danger text-info pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">'+
            '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>'+
            '</a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        $('#showFilters').append(html);
    });
    function addChildFilter(groupId) {
        let selectedField = $('#group' + groupId).find('.field').first().val();
        console.log(selectedField);
        if (selectedField == 1) {
            let html = '<div class="w-100">'+
                '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 position-relative">'+
                '<label for="name">Check Box Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            $('#group' + groupId).find('.showGroups').append(html);
        }
        if (selectedField == 2) {
            let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="name">Color Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="code">Code Color</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="code" class="form-control jscolor" name="filters['+count+'][code]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            $('#group' + groupId).find('.showGroups').append(html);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're adding the same code with elements with the same id, so when you're selecting one with `$('#showGroups')` it will go from top to bottom on the html and find the first one.

So what I did was adding a new variable called `group` that will keep the count of the group number, and assigned it along the id and send it on your `addChildFilter` method.

You can check the solution here: (Also note that you'll have the same problem with other id's like the `$('#field')` one you have there.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div id="showFilters">
      <!-- GROUP -->
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 text-center mt-4">
      <p>Add new group</p>
      <a id="addFilter" class="bg-primary text-white pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let count = 0;
    let group = 0;
    $('#addFilter').click(function() {
      count++;
      group++;
      let html = '<div class="position-relative">' +
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">' +
        '<label for="name">Name</label>' +
        '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters[' + count + '][name]">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">' +
        '<label for="latin">Latin</label>' +
        '<input type="text" id="latin" class="form-control" name="filters[' + count + '][latin]">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">' +
        '<label for="field">Select a field</label>' +
        '<select id="field" class="form-select" name="filters[' + count + '][field]">' +
        '<option value="1">CheckBox</option>' +
        '<option value="2">Color</option>' +
        '</select>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div id="showGroups' + group + '"> ' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="w-100 text-center">' +
        '<p>Add new subgroup.</p>' +
        '<a onclick="addChildFilter(' + group + ')" class="bg-danger text-info pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">' +
        '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>' +
        '</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
      $('#showFilters').append(html);
    });

    function addChildFilter(group) {
      count++;
      let selectedField = $('#field').val();
      if (selectedField == 1) {
        let html = '<div class="w-100">' +
          '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 position-relative">' +
          '<label for="name">Check Box Name</label>' +
          '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters[' + count + '][name]">' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        $('#showGroups' + group).append(html);
      }
      if (selectedField == 2) {
        let html = '<div class="position-relative">' +
          '<div class="row">' +
          '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">' +
          '<label for="name">Color Name</label>' +
          '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters[' + count + '][name]">' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">' +
          '<label for="code">Code Color</label>' +
          '<input type="text" id="code" class="form-control jscolor" name="filters[' + count + '][code]">' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        $('#showGroups').append(html);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div id="showFilters">
        <!-- GROUP -->
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 text-center mt-4">
        <p>Add new form</p>
        <a id="addFilter" class="bg-primary text-white pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $('#addFilter').click(function () {
        count++;
        let html = '<div id="group' + count + '" class="position-relative">'+
            '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="name">Name</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="latin">Latin</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="latin" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][latin]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="field">Select a field</label>'+
            '<select class="form-select field" name="filters['+count+'][field]">'+
            '<option value="1">CheckBox</option>'+
            '<option value="2">Color</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="showGroups" class="showGroups"> '+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="w-100 text-center">'+
            '<p>Add new box.</p>'+
            '<a onclick="addChildFilter('+count+')" class="bg-danger text-info pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">'+
            '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>'+
            '</a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        $('#showFilters').append(html);
    });
    function addChildFilter(groupId) {
        let selectedField = $('#group' + groupId).find('.field').first().val();
        console.log(selectedField);
        if (selectedField == 1) {
            let html = '<div class="w-100">'+
                '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 position-relative">'+
                '<label for="name">Check Box Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            $('#group' + groupId).find('.showGroups').append(html);
        }
        if (selectedField == 2) {
            let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="name">Color Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="code">Code Color</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="code" class="form-control jscolor" name="filters['+count+'][code]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            $('#group' + groupId).find('.showGroups').append(html);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace <a onclick="addChildFilter()" to onclick="addChildFilter(this)"
and replace your function addChildFilter() to this:

```
function addChildFilter(e) {
    count++;
    let element = $(e).parents('.position-relative').find('#showGroups');
    let selectedField = $('#field').val();
    if (selectedField == 1) {
        let html = '<div class="w-100">'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 position-relative">'+
            '<label for="name">Check Box Name</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        element.append(html);
    }
    if (selectedField == 2) {
        let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
            '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="name">Color Name</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="code">Code Color</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="code" class="form-control jscolor" name="filters['+count+'][code]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        element.append(html);
    }
}
```